# Dart/Flutter - Compare two List<dynamic> if they have the same value of id

Tags: list, flutter, dart, contains

I have two `List<dynamic>` and I am trying to figure out how I can check if there is a same value in the `id` field

```
List list1 = [
  {"id": 2, "name": "test1"},
  {"id": 3, "name": "test3"}
];

List list2 = [
  {"id": 2, "name": "test1"}
];
```

I tried this but it returns me false

```
var isMatch = (list1.toSet().intersection(list2.toSet()).length > 0);
```

Comment: You have to specify. There is no way to compare `dynamic`, because it's... dynamic.

Comment: converting it to List<String> will suffice?

Comment: Converting to `String` (as json?) will not help you with searching. You can try to convert it to new class. For example class `User` with fields `id` and `name`. And you can use it as `List<User>`

Comment: oh. it means that to be able to compare it, I need to convert it to a List<object> and they needs to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

You CAN compare dynamics. It's really easy.

```
dynamic a = 0;
dynamic b = 1;
a.compareTo(b);
```

However, this only works iff `a` has a function `compareTo`. All primitives have this function, so no problem. If you have custom classes, then you should write a function `compareTo` yourself.

Also, `b` must be the same object as `a`. So it is good practice to check `if (a.runtimeType == b.runtimeType)` first. In your case this is true obviously.

Answer (score -1):

You can not compare like that because you can't compare dynamic as Boken said, you need to create a class for your object and implement a basic search , you can convert list2 into a set to make the search less complex (contains function)

```
void main() {
  List list1 = [
  MyObject(2,"test"),
  MyObject(3,"test1")
];

List list2 = [
  MyObject(4,"test")
];
  
  
  for(int i=0;i<list1.length;i++){
    
    if(list2.contains(list1[i])){
      // do your logic
      print(true);
      break;
    }
    
  }
  
}

class MyObject{
  
  int id;
  String name;
  
  MyObject(int id,String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  // redifine == operator
  bool operator ==(o) => (o as MyObject).id == this.id;
  
  
}
```